# According to the Ramban, Did all the descendants of all the Sh'vatim observe the Torah before it was given?

Tags: mitzvah, parashat-toldot, ramban

From the Ramban in [Beraishis 26:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ramban_on_Genesis.26.5.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) it seems that not only *Avraham Avinu* kept the Torah, but also his descendants, including Yaakov, Yosef, Amram, Moshe etc. He derives this from the passuk "*that he [Avraham] commanded his children and his household after him to walk in His ways*".

According to this opinion of the Ramban, How far did this continue? Did all the descendants of all the *Sh'vatim* (All the (future) Jewish people up until *Matan Torah*) observe the Torah before it was given?